# Метка не формируется внутри фрейма, а занимает весь root

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Не понимаю, отчего метка не создается внутри фрейма

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title('Метка внутри фрейма')
root.geometry('300x500+100+100')

frame_top=Frame(root, bg='#666', width = 300, height = 100)
frame_top.pack(side='top')

label_top = Label(frame_top, text='Текст метки', bg='green', fg='red', width=200, height=30, font='Arial 14 bold italic', justify=LEFT)
label_top.pack(side='bottom')

print(label_top.cget('width'),label_top.cget('height'))

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверил в Python 3.7 и 2.7 - одинаковый результат :(

Comment: Ребята, что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключите `pack_propagate` он не позволяет виджетам внутри фрейма контролировать размер самого фрейма.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title('Метка внутри фрейма')
root.geometry('300x500+100+100')

frame_top=Frame(root, bg='#666', width = 400, height = 100)
frame_top.pack(side='top')
frame_top.pack_propagate(0)
label_top = Label(frame_top, text='Текст метки', bg='green', fg='red', width=20, height=5, font='Arial 14 bold italic', justify=LEFT)[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
label_top.pack(side='bottom')

print(label_top.cget('width'),label_top.cget('height'))

root.mainloop()
```

---

Так же можно использовать `place` где можно указать конкретные параметры установки виджета

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title('Метка внутри фрейма')
root.geometry('300x500+100+100')

frame_top=Frame(root, bg='#666', width=400, height=200)
frame_top.pack(side='top')
label_top = Label(frame_top, text='Текст метки', bg='green', fg='red', font='Arial 14 bold italic', justify=LEFT)
label_top.place(x=120, y=150, w=150, h=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Щиро дякую!!!!!

Comment: @СергейИвановичХозин [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)